# How to combine or merge multiple values inside the single array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an `array` values. Inside the `array` some `multiple` data but how to `combine or merge` these `multiple records`.
some values inside the single array are  multiples . How to merge these ?

```
    Array
    (
    [0] => plxliupp
    [1] => plxliupp
    [2] => dg_w12
    [3] => col4312
    [4] => Iphone6s
    [5] => Ndry_milk
    [6] => smj7
    [7] => ovn 02 o3
    [8] => allwin6406f
    )
```

After remove `multiples` values. `array` like this

```
    Array
    (
    [0] => plxliupp
    [1] => dg_w12
    [2] => col4312
    [3] => Iphone6s
    [4] => Ndry_milk
    [5] => smj7
    [6] => ovn 02 o3
    [7] => allwin6406f
    )
```

thanks for answering

Comment: https://www.php.net/array_unique?

Comment: [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), or [`array_unique`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) - take your pick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array("a" => "moon", "star", "b" => "moon", "star", "sky");

// Deleting the duplicate items
$result = array_unique($array);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: This question was marked as a dupe, why would you answer it?